# Additional spaces when having for loop

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I'm getting an additional white spaces. I expect that the first post will align in the trends panel in the right side but the actual result was there was a space above the first post.

This is my code that result to have an additional spaces.

```
{% for ctr in  id%}
   <div class="border">
       <a href="#" class="badge badge-danger p-2 float-right"> Bug </a>
       <div class="card-header"> 
          ...
       </div>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If I remove the `for` loop, i'm getting the actual result.

**Actual result:**

When I add the for loop, I get this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7mk3.jpg)

**Expected Result:**

When there is no for loop, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uduq.jpg)

Here are both [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLNo9.jpg)

Comment: both of your image links are looking same, what is exactly expected result, please try to explain more.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's okay now.

Comment: it's fine now, but still your question lacks due to very less effort code illustration, explain more in source so people would able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning!

Did you thought of moving your boarder div tag outside of the loop like e.g.

```
<div class="border">
{% for ctr in  id%}
       <a href="#" class="badge badge-danger p-2 float-right"> Bug </a>
       <div class="card-header"> 
          ...
       </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

or is this the container for each card?

another solution would be to work with the css child command like the following

```py
<div class="badges">
{% for ctr in  id%}
<div class="border">
       <a href="#" class="badge badge-danger p-2 float-right"> Bug </a>
       <div class="card-header"> 
          ...
       </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```css
<style>
.badges div:first-child.border {
  margin-top: ...;

}
</style>
```

Comment: For the first solution, it got aligned but the result is [this](https://imgur.com/YGNpqqu). The "Bug" badge moves up and all the posts are compact. The second solution still the same.

Comment: Did you add some margin settings for the second one like -10px?

Comment: There are no extra margin and padding.

Comment: Ah what i mean is to add this in a separate style command, do you now what i mean?